Issue while returning array of objects from graphQL query response
hey I'm using graphQL with NestJS and Apollo Server.
The issue is I can return one object but while returing array of objects it's throwing error.
Please find the response I want to return:
    {
      data: [
        Post { // using typeOrm Repository API, this Post tye is coming from there
          id: 1,
          uuid: 'f2504a79-dce9-4a14-bb91-162eaa2a75b1',
          title: 'Dummy.',
          modifiedAt: null
          // few more fields
        },
        Post {
          id: 2,
          uuid: 'e17afbd6-46fc-4f5f-8181-a045cb38ae27',
          title: 'resp.',
          modifiedAt: null,
          // few more fields
        },
      ],
      count: 6
    }

Below is my Resolver:
    @Query((returns) => ValidatePostRespTypeDto)
    async getPost(@Args('getPostData',
    new ValidationPipe({ transform: true, transformOptions: { enableImplicitConversion: true } })) 
    getPostData: GetPostInputType, @Context("req") req: any): Promise<ValidatePostRespTypeDto> {
        validateData(getPostData, getPostDataQueryValidator);
        return await this.postService.getPostData(getPostData, req);
    }

Here Comes the DTO:
import { Field, ObjectType } from "@nestjs/graphql";

@ObjectType()
export class ValidatePostDto {
    @Field()
    uuid: String;
    @Field()
    title: String;
    @Field()
    body: string;
    @Field({ nullable: true })
    tags?: string;
    @Field({ nullable: true })
    links?: string;
    @Field({ nullable: true })
    attachment?: string;
    @Field()
    createdAt: Date;
    @Field({ nullable: true })
    modifiedAt?: Date;
}

@ObjectType()
export class ValidatePostRespTypeDto {
    @Field(() => ValidatePostDto)
    data: ValidatePostDto | ValidatePostDto[];
    @Field()
    count: number;
}

Can anyone please help me to understand what's the issue here. I'm using below GQL query to get data;
query{
  getPost(getPostData: {page: 1, limit: 100}) {
    count
    data {
      uuid
      title
      body
      createdAt
      tags
      links
      attachment
      modifiedAt
    }
  }
}

Error:
"message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field ValidatePostDto.uuid.",

Can anyone please help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

Well I was blind, the DTO should be like below,
@ObjectType()
export class ValidatePostRespTypeDto {
    @Field(() => [ValidatePostDto])
    data: ValidatePostDto | ValidatePostDto[];
    @Field()
    count: number;
}

